# Uncheck all Checkboxes in all Google Sheets Tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this script to uncheck all checkboxes in the PRODUCE tab. But I am wanting to uncheck all checkboxes in ALL tabs and not sure how to alter the `getSheetByName` to do so, or if that is even needed:

```js
function checkBoxes() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Produce")
  ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1).setValue(false)
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample sheet with dummy values, since I would want to clarify if all checkboxes are in the same designated range for all tabs/sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, here is the script you need based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498834/looping-a-script-through-all-sheets).

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheets();

  for (var sheets of ws) {
     sheets.getRange(2,1,sheets.getLastRow()-1).setValue(false);
  }
}
```

Let me know if there are any clarifications/modifications needed.

Comment: Great! Just wondering how to exclude a sheet now, because I see now that I don't want it to do anything to the "Shopping List" tab/sheet.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function checkBoxes() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(s => s.getRange("A1:A" + s.getLastRow()).uncheck()); // Or, if you want to uncheck all checkboxes in the sheet, please use sheets.forEach(s => s.getDataRange().uncheck());
}
```

- When `uncheck()` is used, only the checkboxes are unchecked.

#### Note:

- If you want to set the exclude sheets, you can also use the following modification.

  ```
    functioncheckBoxes() {
      const excludeSheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet3",,,]; // If you want to set the exclude sheets, please put the sheet names.

      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const sheets = ss.getSheets();
      sheets.forEach(s => {
        if (!excludeSheets.includes(s.getSheetName())) {
          s.getRange("A1:A" + s.getLastRow()).uncheck(); // Or, if you want to uncheck all checkboxes in the sheet, please use sheets.forEach(s => s.getDataRange().uncheck());
        }
      });
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [uncheck()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)